# What is the best way to create a glass or ice effect in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I have tried blending and this seems to provide a basic glass effect but I feel there must be a better way to generate a glass or ice style effect. What would people suggest ? Is there something that can be done with semi-transparent textures ?

Comment: That depends entirely on the grade of realism you want to achieve with your simulation.

Comment: "Semi-transparent textures" also use blending. While it's an interesting question, I don't think it's fit for Stack Overflow, because it's too broad.

Comment: Sampling the back buffer with slightly disturbed texture coordinates (based on normals) and doing a slight shift to blue would be another possible implementation. Fresnel, volumetric lighting and texturing and backscattering are things you can consider, depending on how realistic you want it. Several chapters in the GPU Gems series have been written about this, and one could probably write a complete book about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very broad and complex question and the answer entirely depends on what kind of result (in terms of realism etc.) you are trying to get, what kind of lighting you want etc. Most of these effects, and materials in general, are the domain of shaders. A lot can be achieved with choosing the right textures with the right material parameters - again depending on what you consider an acceptable result.

GPU Gems book has a chapter on glass simulation (see 19.3.2):
[GPU Gems 2 - Generic Refraction Simulation](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/gpugems2/part-ii-shading-lighting-and-shadows/chapter-19-generic-refraction-simulation)

When it comes to ice, there are again a ton of different things to consider depending on the complexity you want - see this answer here:
[How to render realistic ice?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26225/how-to-render-realistic-ice)